# How to show that $|\nabla f|\ge \sqrt 2$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $[0,1]^2\subset U\subset \mathbb R^2$ where $U$ is open, and let $f: U\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function with $f(0,0)=3$ and $f(1,1)=1$. Prove that $|\nabla f|\ge \sqrt 2$ somewhere in $U$.

The only idea I had is to apply Taylor's formula
[image]
but it only gives something like $-2=f(1,1)-f(0,0)=f_x(1,1)+f_y(1,1)$, which holds at a point, and I guess "somewhere" means "on a subset". Moreover, I don't know how to get hold of $f_x^2+f_y^2=||\nabla f|| ^2$.

Any hints please? (If I only use hints as opposed to reading a solution I hope I will learn more.)

Comment: Do you mean [0,1]×{0}?

Comment: Did you mean that [0,1] is the segment connecting (0,0) to (1,1)? Otherwise there are countexamples...

Comment: I fixed this typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Mean value theorem in one variable, applied to $f(x,y)$ on the line segment connecting $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

You also might have a theorem in your book which gives a version of the mean value theorem that applies in the setting of your question. It will basically derive from the above idea.

Comment: This gives $\exists \xi \in (0,1)$ such that $f_x(\xi,\xi)+f_y(\xi,\xi)=-2$. What am I supposed to do next (if I don't come up with the observation in the other answer)? Also, Taylor's formula I referred to in the question gives the same result with $\xi=1$, doesn't it?

Comment: so $\nabla f (\xi,\xi) \cdot (1,1) = -2$. Then use $|a \cdot b| \leq |a| |b|$ (Cauchy-Schwartz).

Comment: I see, so in any case I guess I need to note that $f_x+f_y$ is the dot product. And I can use Taylor's formula instead of the MVT, right? (I don't know how can one come up with the fact that they need to use the MVT for $\phi(t)=f(t,t)$ on $(0,1)$.)

Comment: With Taylor's theorem you have no way to know what the $g_i(x)$ are, which makes numerical estimates difficult.

Comment: Why I have no way to know what the $g_i(x)$ are? The version of the theorem I cited says that they are the partials, and the formula gives $-2=f(1,1)-f(0,0)=f_x(1,1)+f_y(1,1)$.

Comment: They are only the partials at $p$, but can be just about anything away from $p$. What you wrote there isn't correct, it's actually $f(1,1) - f(0,0) = g_1(1,1) + g_2(1,1)$. And $g_1$ is only equal to $f_x$ at the origin, similarly for $g_2$ and $f_y$.

Comment: Oh, yes, that should be $-2=f(1,1)-f(0,0)=f_x(0,0)+f_y(0,0)$. But isn't this enough? This gives $2=|\nabla f (0,0) \cdot (1,1)^t|\le |\nabla f (0,0)| \sqrt 2$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

By MVT we have that $\exists c=a+(b-a)t\quad t\in(0,1)$

$$f(b)-f(a)=\frac{\partial f(c)}{\partial \vec v}|b-a|$$

with $\vec v=\frac{b-a}{|b-a|}$ and for $f$ differentiable we have

$$\frac{\partial f(c)}{\partial \vec v}=\langle \nabla f(c),\vec v\rangle=\frac1{|b-a|}\langle \nabla f(c), b-a\rangle$$

therefore

$$f(b)-f(a)=\langle \nabla f(c), b-a\rangle$$

that is

$$2=f(0,0)-f(1,1)=\langle \nabla f(c), (-1,-1)\rangle=|\nabla f(c)|\sqrt 2 \cos \theta$$

and finally

$$|\nabla f(c)|=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\cos \theta}\ge \sqrt 2$$

Comment: Could I use Taylor's formula instead? (This would give your formula with $c=(1,1)$, as I pointed out in the question.) And in general, under what conditions is the second formula (the one involving $\cos$) for the dot product valid?

Comment: The given equality is valid for f differentiable, I will add some detail on that asap. I think we need to use MVT.